# redirect http to https in jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, https, jhipster, http-redirect, undertow

I have a jhipster (4.14.5) Monolithic application using Spring Boot that runs with http v2 on production and uses a certificate to force ssl. The application server uses an embedded undertow container that is created using the automatic builder (which is a standard configuration in jhipster).

Unfortunately, it does not automatically forward users on the production server who use http in their browser to https. I tried many different possible solutions to this problem including

```
security:
  require-ssl: true
```

in application-prod.yml

and

```
http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
and.portMapper().http(80).mapsTo(443)
```

in the SecurityConfiguration

and

```
underTowContainer.addBuilderCustomizers(builder -> builder.addHttpListener(80, hostAddress));
        underTowContainer.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo -> {
            deploymentInfo.addSecurityConstraint(new SecurityConstraint()
                .addWebResourceCollection(new WebResourceCollection().addUrlPattern("/*"))
                .setTransportGuaranteeType(TransportGuaranteeType.CONFIDENTIAL)
                .setEmptyRoleSemantic(SecurityInfo.EmptyRoleSemantic.PERMIT))
                .setConfidentialPortManager(exchange -> 443);
        });
```

in WebConfigurer

However, no approach has worked so far. Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

The WebFlux code below worked for me.

```
// Spring MVC
http.requiresChannel(channel -> channel
    .requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null).requiresSecure());
    
// WebFlux
http.redirectToHttps(redirect -> redirect
    .httpsRedirectWhen(e -> e.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey("X-Forwarded-Proto")));
```

Reference: https://www.jhipster.tech/security/

Answer (score 0):

do you use some proxy like nginx or something like a load balancer? 
i would suggest using it for https forwarding.

Comment: No, we don't use something like this at the moment. We thought the redirect is possible directly as jhipster is using the undertow component which should support it

Comment: ok, i understand. then normally `security.require-ssl=true` and `.anyRequest().requiresSecure()`  should do the work.

Comment: Could there be any other code that prevents this or that interferes with the redirect?

Comment: for me this configuration is sufficent to redirect to https `http
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest().requiresSecure()`. maybe the `underTowContainer.addBuilderCustomizers` thing is redundant?

Comment: @skrusche Did you find the solution for your problem? If so please post it here. Thank you!